# Get marker infowindow using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using Rails 4 and gem gmaps4rails. How can I get marker.infowindow in js?
Here is my code:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {scrollwheel: false}, internal: {id: 'event-detail-map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
      {
          "lat": "<%= @event.location.latitude %>",
          "lng": "<%= @event.location.longitude %>",
          "infowindow": 'Hello!'
      }  
  ]);
  marker = markers[0];
  marker.getServiceObject().addListener('mouseover', function () {
      marker.infowindow.open(marker.serviceObject.map,   marker.serviceObject);
  });

  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  center = {lat: <%= @event.location.latitude %>, lng: <%=@event.location.longitude %>};

  handler.map.centerOn(center);
  handler.getMap().setZoom(12);
});
```

Console writes me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

Comment: Also I noticed after click on marker all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `marker.infowindow.open` use `marker.infowindow.render_to_string` refer this link (https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller)

Comment: No, it doesn't help. When I put  `marker.infowindow`  in wbrowser console it returns "undefined"

Comment: please refer this (http://www.sitepoint.com/use-google-maps-rails/) for custom marker infowindow